# Dynamic form in active admin based on checkbox values using ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, activeadmin

I'm a newbie to rails. I need assistance to show a dynamic form in active admin. I need a check box to select either credit/debit. Based on the value selected from checkbox, I want to display two different forms. How can I do that using JS? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use seperate partials for this. You can send a js request to controller at checkbox onchange event and render different partials for debit & credit.

Comment: Thank you so much @muhammadYawarAli. But how can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not necessary to tell us whether you're new to a language, we just want you to put effort into your question by researching then asking the question well. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need to see evidence of your effort, either as the places you looked and an explanation of why those didn't help, or the minimal code and data demonstrating the problem you're asking about. As is it looks like you want us to write the code for you, which is not what SO is for,  instead of help you fix the problem, which is the SO way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a form partial & in that partial you can put javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(function(){
        $('#checkbox_name_id').change(function() {
            // call a controller action and in return render the partial
               in html.
        });
    });
</script>
```